# SageMath: defining class of functions on Elliptic Curves

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, sagemath

In SageMath,

I would like to manipulate rational functions on elliptic curves (defined on finite fields). For example, for $P = (x,y)$ on some curve $E$

$$f = x+y-12$$
$$g = \frac{x+y-3}{(x-3)^2} $$ etc.

Is there a natural class  ?

I am looking to make a toy example with pairings, so I need to define stuff like $$P \rightarrow f_P$$ where $$f_P:Q \rightarrow f_P(Q)$$ is a function

I can't see how to do that, and I'm able to make computations if I define

```
def f (P,Q):
   ....
```

but I can only compute the values taken by the function $f_P$, I cannot "see" the function $f_P$. Basically I'm trying as an exercise to re-write the following Magma code to SageMath:

http://www.craigcostello.com.au/pairings/beginners/5-3-1-TateWeilMiller.txt

EDIT:
my question hasn't attracted much interest so i'm going to give a more concrete example:

```
# this is the beginning of the code related to the example in Costello
q=47
F = GF(q)
R.<x> = F[] ; R
F4.<u>= F.extension(x^4-4*x^2+5) 
a = 21 ; b= 15
E = EllipticCurve(F4,[a,b])
r=17
k=4 
(q^4-1) % r # r=17 is a divisor of q^4 - 1 = 47^4 - 1
P = E([45,23])
P.order()
h = E.cardinality() / r^2
O = E(0)
Q = E([5*u^3 + 37*u + 13,7*u^3 + 45*u^2 + 10*u + 7])

def fADD_(P,Q,x,y):
    lamb_da=(Q[1]-P[1])/(Q[0]-P[0])
    c =P[1]-lamb_da*P[0]
    l =(y-(lamb_da*x+c))
    v =(x-(lamb_da^2-P[0]-P[1]))
    return (l/v)
```

fADD_(P,Q,x,y) will return an error while i would have liked it to return a rational function in x,y

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel.bin_op
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce.c:9946)()    1195         try:
> -> 1196             action = self._action_maps.get(xp, yp, op)    1197         except KeyError:
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce_dict.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce_dict.TripleDict.get
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce_dict.c:7917)()    1327
> if not valid(cursor.key_id1):
> -> 1328             raise KeyError((k1, k2, k3))    1329         value = cursor.value
>
> KeyError: (Finite Field in u of size 47^4, Symbolic Ring, )
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 fADD_(P,Q,x,y)
>
> in fADD_(P, Q, x, y)
> 2     lamb_da=(Q[Integer(1)]-P[Integer(1)])/(Q[Integer(0)]-P[Integer(0)])
> 3     c =P[Integer(1)]-lamb_da*P[Integer(0)]
> ----> 4     l =(y-(lamb_da*x+c))
> 5     v =(x-(lamb_da**Integer(2)-P[Integer(0)]-P[Integer(1)]))
> 6     return (l/v)
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/element.pyx
> in sage.structure.element.Element.**mul**
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:12034)()    1515
> return (left).*mul*(right)    1516         if
> BOTH_ARE_ELEMENT(cl):
> -> 1517             return coercion_model.bin_op(left, right, mul)    1518     1519         cdef long value
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel.bin_op
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce.c:9996)()    1196
> action = self._action_maps.get(xp, yp, op)    1197         except
> KeyError:
> -> 1198             action = self.get_action(xp, yp, op, x, y)    1199         if action is not None:    1200             if
> (action)._is_left:
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel.get_action
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce.c:16783)()    1725
> except KeyError:    1726             pass
> -> 1727         action = self.discover_action(R, S, op, r, s)    1728         action = self.verify_action(action, R, S, op)    1729
> self._action_maps.set(R, S, op, action)
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel.discover_action
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce.c:18201)()    1856         """
> 1857         if isinstance(R, Parent):
> -> 1858             action = (R).get_action(S, op, True, r, s)    1859             if action is not None:    1860                 return
> action
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/parent.pyx
> in sage.structure.parent.Parent.get_action
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/parent.c:19901)()    2475
> action = self.*get_action*(S, op, self_on_left)    2476         if
> action is None:
> -> 2477             action = self.discover_action(S, op, self_on_left, self_el, S_el)    2478     2479         if action is not None:
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/parent.pyx
> in sage.structure.parent.Parent.discover_action
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/parent.c:20878)()    2554
>
> ## detect actions defined by *rmul*, *lmul*, *act_on*, and *acted_upon* methods    2555                 from .coerce_actions import
>
> detect_element_action
> -> 2556                 action = detect_element_action(self, S, self_on_left, self_el, S_el)    2557                 if action is not
> None:    2558                     return action
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce_actions.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce_actions.detect_element_action
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce_actions.c:5026)()
> 215     if isinstance(x, ModuleElement) and isinstance(y, Element):
> 216         try:
> --> 217             return (RightModuleAction if X_on_left else LeftModuleAction)(Y, X, y, x)
> 218         except CoercionException as msg:
> 219             _record_exception()
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce_actions.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce_actions.ModuleAction.**init**
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce_actions.c:6778)()
> 361         if not isinstance(g, Element) or not isinstance(a, ModuleElement):
> 362             raise CoercionException("not an Element acting on a ModuleElement")
> --> 363         res = self.act(g, a)
> 364         if parent(res) is not the_set:
> 365             # In particular we will raise an error if res is None
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/categories/action.pyx
> in sage.categories.action.Action.act
> (build/cythonized/sage/categories/action.c:4115)()
> 213             5*x
> 214         """
> --> 215         return self._act_convert(g, x)
> 216
> 217     def **invert**(self):
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/categories/action.pyx
> in sage.categories.action.Action._act_convert
> (build/cythonized/sage/categories/action.c:3759)()
> 169         if parent(x) is not U:
> 170             x = U(x)
> --> 171         return self.*act*(g, x)
> 172
> 173     cpdef *act*(self, g, x):
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce_actions.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce_actions.RightModuleAction.*act*
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce_actions.c:8600)()
> 629             g = <Element?>self.connecting.*call*(g)
> 630         if self.extended_base is not None:
> --> 631             a = <ModuleElement?>self.extended_base(a)
> 632         return (a).*lmul*(g)  # a * g
> 633
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/parent.pyx
> in sage.structure.parent.Parent.**call**
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/parent.c:9218)()
> 898         if mor is not None:
> 899             if no_extra_args:
> --> 900                 return mor.*call*(x)
> 901             else:
> 902                 return mor._call_with_args(x, args, kwds)
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce_maps.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce_maps.DefaultConvertMap_unique.*call*
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce_maps.c:4556)()
> 159                 print(type(C), C)
> 160                 print(type(C._element_constructor), C._element_constructor)
> --> 161             raise
> 162
> 163     cpdef Element _call_with_args(self, x, args=(), kwds={}):
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce_maps.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce_maps.DefaultConvertMap_unique.*call*
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce_maps.c:4448)()
> 154         cdef Parent C = self._codomain
> 155         try:
> --> 156             return C._element_constructor(x)
> 157         except Exception:
> 158             if print_warnings:
>
> /Applications/SageMath-9.1.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/symbolic/ring.pyx
> in sage.symbolic.ring.SymbolicRing.*element_constructor*
> (build/cythonized/sage/symbolic/ring.cpp:6648)()
> 377         elif isinstance(x, (RingElement, Matrix)):
> 378             if x.parent().characteristic():
> --> 379                 raise TypeError('positive characteristic not allowed in symbolic computations')
> 380             exp = x
> 381         elif isinstance(x, Factorization):
>
> TypeError: positive characteristic not allowed in symbolic
> computations

Comment: Certainly the keyword here is probably "function field" since your rational functions live inside $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}(E)$, although I am not sure how they are implemented in Sage, or how to evaluate them at points.

Comment: I don't understand that piece of Magma, so I can't tell exactly what you want. If you just want to take the function $f(P,Q)$ and fix $P$ to get a function $f_P(Q)$ then in Sage you can do something like f_P = lambda Q : f(P,Q).

Comment: stupid example  $f_P$ could be $Q \rightarrow P+Q$

Comment: it's like doing a partial evaluation of a function of 2 variables F(X,Y). if you fix $X=X_0$ you are left with a function $F_{X_0}(Y)$ i am interested in seeing the details of $F_{X_0}$ because i want to manipulate the coefficients to create new functions

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "see the details". If you have $f(P,Q) = f(P_1,P_2,Q_1,Q_2)$ defined as a rational function in sage, then to figure out $f_P$ as a rational function, you can just evaluate $f(P_1,P_2,x,y)$ where $x,y$ are two variables. It will then print out what you want, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It was hard (for me) to find the starting point of the question. You are working i a concrete situation and the task is clear, but i had to guess which is the point of the question. (We want to "translate" some magma code to sage? Or we want to correct the sage code snippet only? Or the question is the reason for the long traceback information?)

This answer is "making the sage code work". (If something else is the subject of the question, please edit.) Note first that the given code is not complete, well `y` is not defined. This may be also the reason for the error. (If it is a variable, or it is not "married" structurally with `x`, then i would expect such errors.)

---

The following piece of code worked for me:

```
p = 47
F = GF(p)
R.<x>  = PolynomialRing(F)
F4.<u> = GF(p^4, modulus=x^4 - 4*x^2 + 5)

a, b = 21, 15
E = EllipticCurve(F4, [a,b])
print(f"Working with the elliptic curve E:\n{E}")

r = 17
k = 4
print("Is r = {} dividing p^4 - 1 = {}? {}"
      .format(r, p^4 - 1, r.divides(p^4 - 1)))

P = E.point([45, 23])
print(f"The order of the point {P.xy()} is {P.order()}")

h = E.cardinality() / r^2
O = E(0)
Q = E.point([5*u^3 + 37*u + 13, 7*u^3 + 45*u^2 + 10*u + 7])

R.<x,y> = PolynomialRing(F)
# or F4 instead of F, to avoid structural coerce

def myadd(P, Q, x, y):
    m = (Q[1] - P[1]) / (Q[0] - P[0])
    c = P[1] - m*P[0]
    return (y - (m*x+c)) / (x - (m^2 - P[0] - P[1]))

myadd(P, Q, x, y)
```

(Please try to give a readable shape to the code, i also
break pep8 rules, but spaces make reading (and error searching) easier.)

---

The above gave me:

```
Working with the elliptic curve E:
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 21*x + 15
    over Finite Field in u of size 47^4
Is r = 17 dividing p^4 - 1 = 4879680? True
The order of the point (45, 23) is 17
((5*u^3 + 22*u^2 + 2*u - 4)*x 
    + y + (10*u^3 - 3*u^2 + 4*u + 16))
/
(x + (12*u^3 - 4*u^2 - 12*u + 17))
```

(... manually rearrange to better fit the stackexchange format.)

And indeed, the result of `myadd(P, Q, x, y)` is a rational function in `x` and `y`, defined over `F4`.

(I will try to see what happens in the other code, but i do not have magma on this own linux machine.)